# HTML5 - mouse move event are called not fast enough

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I show a small image near the mouse pointer in my app. 
I have a bug that the image is not following the pointer fast enough, and that because the mouse move events are not called fast enough.

I wonder why it happens and how i can improve that?

Comment: Code is worth 0x400 words. We can't help you by pointing out inefficiencies in your code if you don't show it.

Comment: I wonder if anyone will be able to help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the mouse anywhere fast enough there will be large jumps in how it moves - you cannot perfect it any more I don't think.

Comment: How could you know? With exactly no data to work with? For all you know his `mousemove` handler is doing all manner of inefficient, time-wasting things.

Comment: I am assuming that he would have taken that into account for speed as a variable thing all the time.

Comment: @phunanon With the nature of JS immigrants from PHP/Java/C++, people who learn jQuery before the actual language, the inefficiencies of DOM reflow on top of repainting, and people just misusing events to stuff all of their operations into the callback, rather than using the callback to simply update state, and then either binding the state to a callback, or polling for state-changes at a given interval... ...it's very easy to do things which cripple performance, starting with `el.onmousemove = function () { $(this).doStuff(); };` as a prime-target for inefficiency.

Comment: @Norguard You mean using something like `requestAnimationFrame` for positionning the image, with `mousemove` only updating a pair of variables to track the last known position of the mouse pointer?

Comment: It's certainly a possibility, and where supported/polyfilled can increase UI-responsiveness while helping to optimize draw calls. But even something as simple as creating your own setInterval or setTimeout, to check for position updates, using a cached (enclosed, or otherwise) reference to the element (instead of a DOM-lookup by ID/etc, each iteration) every 16ms (or whatever) is going to be vastly preferable to doing ALL of the things which could possibly be inefficient in one big ball of jQuery-program-stuffed-in-event, recalculated every iteration, due to lack of caching. We don't know.